# Segment Sagitta calculation from circle radius and chord length

Tags: geometry

If I rest a flat line (say an oversized spaceship) on a circle (say the 2d profile of earth), what is the height of the space ship off the ground on either end?

I tried to combine two of the formula from the wiki page on [Circular Segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment):

$$\theta = 2arcsin\frac{c}{2R}$$

$$c = R(1-\sqrt{\frac{1+cos(\theta)}{2}})$$

$$c = R(1-\sqrt{\frac{1+cos(2arcsin\frac{c}{2R})}{2}})$$

My [calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=h%3DR%281-sqrt%281%2Bcos%282*arcsin%281-sqrt%28c%2F%282*R%29%29%29%29%2F2%29%29%3BR%3D6371%2Cc%3D50) though seems wrong.

Where have I slipped up?

Answer (score 1):

You have $c$ on both sides of the equation after the substitution, but the equation you're using is wrong anyway; you should use $h$ on the left side instead.  Then, you'd need to apply $\cos(2\arcsin(\theta)) = \sqrt{1 - 2 x^2}$.

There is an easier way.

Let $R$ be the radius of the circle the line is resting on, $H$ the minimum height (above the circle) perpendicular to the circle, i.e. the minimum distance between the line and the circle, $d$ the distance from the point on the line closest to the circle and the point where we wish to measure the distance to the circle, and $h$ that distance.

[image: Illustration of a line on top of a circle]

We have a right triangle with one side $d$, the other side $R + H$, and the hypotenuse $R + h$. Using Pythagorean theorem,
$$d^2 + (R + H)^2 = (R + h)^2$$
and solving for $h$ (noting that all variables are lengths and therefore cannot be negative) yields
$$h = \sqrt{(R + H)^2 + d^2} - R$$

For the spaceship case, $R$ is the radius of Earth, $H$ is the height of the spaceship off the ground (if we consider a flat bar, $H = 0$), $d$ is half the length of the spaceship, and $h$ is the height (perpendicular to ground) at the tips of the spaceship.